# splitting of a central extension

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, homological-algebra, group-extensions

I want to prove the following version of the splitting lemma. Let $G,K$ be topological groups.
Let $1\to G\xrightarrow{\phi}H\xrightarrow{\eta}K\to1$ be a central extension of $K$ by $G$. Then $\phi$ and $\eta$ are continuous homomorphisms and $\phi(G)\cong \ker(\eta)\subseteq Z(H)$. Suppose this extension is trivial, i.e. there is a section $\mu:K\to H$ such that $\eta\circ\mu=Id_K$. Then $H\simeq G\times K$.

I define $\Psi:G\times K\to H$ by $\Psi(g,k)=\phi(g)\mu(k)$. Continuity of this map is clear. Also, it is a homomorphism since $\phi(g)\in Z(H)$ for all $g\in G$. I want to show it is an isomorphism, but I am stuck proving both surjectivity and injectivity. To construct an inverse map $\Phi:H\to G\times K$, I want to do something like $\Phi(h)=(…,\eta(h))$ and using that $\mu$ is a section, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Why are $\phi$ and $\eta$ continuous? Anyway, apply exactness to obtain the missing element in $G$: since $\eta(\mu(\eta(h)))=\eta(h)$, we get $h^{-1}\mu(\eta(h))\in\ker\eta=\mathrm{im}\,\phi$...

Comment: Since $G,K$ are topological groups, we consider topological homomorphisms.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. When you say "Then $H\simeq G\times K$", you don't say in which sense. Isomorphism of topological group? It's awkward here if continuity assumptions are implicit. If you want a topological isomorphism, the answer you accepted is not complete.

Comment: Yes I do require an isomorphism of topological groups, i.e. a homeomorphism which is a group homomorphism.

Comment: And therefore, I am still worrying about continuity of the inverse map

Answer (score 1):

**Surjectivity**

For $h\in H$ consider $x=h(\mu\circ\nu)(h^{-1})$.

This gives $\nu(x)=\nu(h)(\nu\circ\mu\circ\nu)(h^{-1})=\nu(h)\nu(h^{-1})=1_K$.

Therefore there is some $g\in G$ with $\phi(g)=x$.

Together we have $h=x(\mu\circ\nu)(h)=\Psi(g,\nu(h))$

**Injectivity**

If $\Psi(g,k)=1$ then $\phi(g)\mu(k)=1_H$ so $\nu\circ\mu(k)=1_K$ so $k=1_K$.

Therefore $\phi(g)=1_H$ so $g=1_G$.

Comment: This is very enlightning. Can we also deduce that $\Psi^{-1}$ is continuous?